# Улучшить качество звука (полученного с микрофона)

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Есть веб-сервис, написанный на питоне.

В него по вебсокету прилетают данные от клиента. Данные приходят с микрофона в строке base64, в ogg формате.

Дальше эта строка уходит в гугл для распознавания голоса в текст.

Каким образом можно улучшить качество записи (убрать шумы, усилить голос и т.п.) на бекенде?

Нюанс в том, что всё это должно быть универсальными для всех клиентов.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что тут возможно простое универсальное решение. Мало ли какие могут быть искажения.

Comment: Вот и я в тупик зашёл. Но... Тот же гугл (speech-to-text) каким-то образом делает препроцессинг файлов. И довольно-таки неплохо

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text

Comment: Ну так гугль много лет над этим работал. И теперь хочет за свои умения денег )

Comment: Вот только я не знаю сервиса (даже платного) у гугла по улучшению качества звука

Comment: Я подозреваю, что даже после всех "улучшений" звука если то, что получилось, распознавать как есть - будет много ошибок. Поэтому гугль и продаёт готовое решение, основанное сразу на многих техниках, а не половинчатую штуку. Кстати, не исключаю, что гугль звук может даже и не чистит в привычном понимании этого термина, а кормит нейросети сырым звуком, а они дальше уже сами разбираются, что сделать со звуком, как его преобразовать, чтобы распознавание текстов шло хорошо в итоге. Т.е. это такой "чёрный ящик" из которого нельзя выделить отдельно "чистый звук".

Comment: Кстати... Как вариант.

Comment: Но. При одинаковом конфиге и том же файле - результат разный. Так что все же как-то обрабатывают файл, имхо.

Comment: https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance
хорошо работает с английским языком. Может чем-нибудь поможет.